# Does Laravel's Validation class Sanitize?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, sanitize

I was unable to find any information in the documentation as to whether or not the Validation class sanitizes data. Everyone seems to use the Validation class for obvious reasons, but I see no sanitization.

Take for example a form with 2 input fields, name and description. In this case, only name is required. Handling the form submission:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array(
        'name' => 'required|min:2'
    )
);
```

Assuming there are no errors with the validation, according to most tutorials (and the documentation), I would simply use;

```
SomeModel::create(array(
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
));
```

Will this class sanitize the data? Or can I expect the data to be the exact same as what I entered on the form? Requiring a minimum of 2 characters is hardly sanitization.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: That's why it's called "Validation" class, it _Validates_ , it doesn't _Sanitize_ : these are two very different concepts, which must be handled separately.

Comment: Obviously. But every tutorial, including those directly on the Laravel site skip sanitization and simply use the validation class. Sanitization is a form of Validation, hence the question.

Comment: Check [Taylor's answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1684).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Laravel doesn't do sanitization.

Add this to `composer.json`

```
"frozennode/xssinput": "dev-master",
```

Then to `config/app.php` to `providers` add

```
'Frozennode\XssInput\XssInputServiceProvider'
```

And to `aliases`

```
'Input'           => 'Frozennode\XssInput\XssInput'
```

Then this would do some sanitization

```
SomeModel::create(array(
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
));
```

Checkout library on github 
https://github.com/FrozenNode/XssInput

This way, you don't need to change your code. Just do

```
composer update
```